# Can I submit a form in popup page to parent page, so parent page moves to other page without a new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Can a Genius help me out here?

I'm working on Spring MVC Web Project with jsp.
There is a parent page that shows list of subject, 
and a popup page shows up when user clicks a subject to check its password.

popup page transfers the inserted password by a form to parent page and close itself, so parent page moves to other page that shows its content.

It works fine in Chrome, but not in Internet Explore.
In IE, popup disappears and another page comes up with its content.

Does any genius know how I prevent the third page, and just have first parent page moves to content page?

Here is my code.
Hope someone help me here....

```
//the form in popup page
<form action="readDetail.do" name="insertedPasswordForm" id="insertPasswordForm" role="form" method="post" target="parentPage">
    <input type="password" id="typedPassword" name="typedPassword"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="privateId" value="${privateId}"/>
</form>

<button  onclick="insertPassword()" style="margin-left:200px;">확인</button>
//submit the form by this button with javascript


//javascript
function insertPassword(){
    opener.name = "parentPage";
    document.insertedPasswordForm.target = "parentPage";
    document.insertedPasswordForm.submit(); 
    window.close();
}
```

Comment: is there any error in browser console?

Comment: No, it actually works fine. but I don't wanna see the third page that shows up after the pop up gets closed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the way to transfer the values.

I used Modal, so there was no need to use pop up.